# Unicode therblig symbols

Tags: unicode

I was wondering if anyone knows if Unicode characters exists for the Therblig symbols?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therblig

Google for some reason only showed me search results for "related searches" and provided no actual results for the search "unicode therblig symbols". (not in quotes)

If these don't exist, does anyone know the procedure for proposing new symbols?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therblig symbols have not been encoded as characters in Unicode (or in other standards). We can be rather sure of this after searching by the name “therblig” in [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/unicode/babelmap.html), because most probably that name would appear in the Unicode names for the characters. They are not in the [proposed characters list](http://www.unicode.org/alloc/Pipeline.html) either, or in the [archive of rejected proposals](http://www.unicode.org/alloc/nonapprovals.html).

If you consider making a proposal, you should try to find evidence of actual use of the symbols *in texts*. Failing to do so is the most common cause of rejection. The procedure is described on the page [Submitting Character Proposals](http://www.unicode.org/pending/proposals.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I suppose my only reason for proposal was for my personal use, but as Unicode seems to be very comprehensive overall, it might be a nice addition.